# convert to list every value is dictionary in python

Tags: python

i have output of print response is

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  480M     0  480M   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs      99M  756K   98M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1     ext4      7.7G  2.9G  4.9G  38% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     492M     0  492M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     492M     0  492M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0     squashfs   18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1480
/dev/loop2     squashfs   90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/loop3     squashfs   92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/8592
```

how to convert it to list or dictionary to easy get value of every filesystem, type and mounted 
then make loop to get every value and put them in variables and use them in the code.

Comment: What do you have tried so far? Is it python 3 or 2?

Comment: You should be able to use a [csv reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) with a custom value separator.

Comment: As noted, we ask that you provide a [mcve[ including sample input AND sample output, as well as _code_ for what you've already tried based on your own research. This is not a code-writing or tutorial site

Comment: The first hard part is to handle `on` inside `Mounted on` without splitting it to another column.

Comment: Hint: look whether the separators are tabs (fix amount) or spaces (variable amount). In the former case you can handle it with the `csv` module, in the latter you should probably try either the `re` module or strip substrings at fixed position. As you have said nothing about where the output comes from, you cannot know for the possible corner cases: looooooooooooooooooong file name or `embedded space` in the Filesystem or Mounted on fields. And IHMO this is the real problem here...

Comment: @felipsmartins python 3

Comment: @JustinasMarozas how i can convert it ?

Comment: @rehamadel to getting started: `buf = io.StringIO("""output here..."""); for line in buf: # be happy`. helpful tools: string replace(), split(), strip(), lists, dicts

Comment: @SergeBallesta the output come from use aws botos 
params_apache={"commands":["sudo systemctl stop apache2"],"workingDirectory":["/home"],"executionTimeout":["600"]}
        response_apache = ssm_client.send_command(DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript", InstanceIds=["i-0fb28a7b3786adee1"],Comment='logging the', TimeoutSeconds=600, Parameters=params_apache, OutputS3BucketName='dashboard.json', OutputS3KeyPrefix='ssm',)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the dictionary iterating over every line like that:

```py
data = '''Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  480M     0  480M   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs      99M  756K   98M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1     ext4      7.7G  2.9G  4.9G  38% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     492M     0  492M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     492M     0  492M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0     squashfs   18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1480
/dev/loop2     squashfs   90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/loop3     squashfs   92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/8592'''

header = ['filesystem', 'type', 'size', 'used', 'avail', 'use%', 'mounted on']
d = {}
for line in data.split('\n')[1:]:
    for i, j in enumerate(line.split()):
        if i == 0:
            fs= j
            d[fs] = {}
        else:
            d[fs][header[i]] = j

print(d)
```

Output:

```py
{

    'udev':{
        'type':'devtmpfs',
        'size':'480M',
        'used':'0',
        'avail':'480M',
        'use%':'0%',
        'mounted on':'/dev'
    },
    'tmpfs':{
        'type':'tmpfs',
        'size':'492M',
        'used':'0',
        'avail':'492M',
        'use%':'0%',
        'mounted on':'/sys/fs/cgroup'
    },
    '/dev/xvda1':{
        'type':'ext4',
        'size':'7.7G',
        'used':'2.9G',
        'avail':'4.9G',
        'use%':'38%',
        'mounted on':'/'
    },
    '/dev/loop0':{
        'type':'squashfs',
        'size':'18M',
        'used':'18M',
        'avail':'0',
        'use%':'100%',
        'mounted on':'/snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1480'
    },
    '/dev/loop2':{
        'type':'squashfs',
        'size':'90M',
        'used':'90M',
        'avail':'0',
        'use%':'100%',
        'mounted on':'/snap/core/8268'
    },
    '/dev/loop3':{
        'type':'squashfs',
        'size':'92M',
        'used':'92M',
        'avail':'0',
        'use%':'100%',
        'mounted on':'/snap/core/8592'
    }

}
```